# need to highlight and search the text in PDF using UIWebView

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, pdf, uiwebview

I am not able to search and highlight the text in PDF using UIWebView. I want PDF on only UIwebView Any Tutorial and Suggestion. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript for that

http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/01/12/search-and-highlight-text-in-uiwebview/

Comment: there if I am taking PDF from Bundle its not workking ,,,its working only for html I need in PDF

Comment: @Er.Maheshwari you marked this as an accepted answer. Does that mean it worked for you with PDF after all?